# Needing explanation for getElementsByClassName("className")[0];

Tags: javascript

In the javascript code further down, can someone please explain to me the purpose/meaning of [0] in the following line of code please? : var contactSpan = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

I understand how all of the code works except for that part. I have included relevant html code linked to that part of my js code for clarity's sake.

I'm fairly new to web coding so please don't use overly technical language if it can be avoided. Thank you:)

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav-demo">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#" id="contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

<div id="contactModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <p>Contact details here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
// Get the button that opens the modal
var contact = document.getElementById('contact');

// Get the modal
var contactModal = document.getElementById('contactModal');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var contactSpan = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
```

Comment: Seen as it's only asking for the first element.  You could use querySelector instead.

Comment: for this line it's asking for the first element, but the next line which doesn't appear here it's asking for the next element so the index changes to [1], then the next line it's [2]. I just couldn't figure out why, but I can now. Thanks for all the very helpful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` according to the `plural` form of `Elements` returns an `array-like` object. There may be more than one element with the class `close`, so why it returns `array-like` object.

`Array` or `array-like` object items can be access using the index of the item which starts from `0`.

You have only one element in your page and your `array-like` object contains only one item, anyway it returns an `array-like` object with one item.

After that you are trying to get the first item using the `[]` index notation which is the current `span` element.

Last line of your code is equivalent to this two statements

```
var elemetsWithClassClose = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
var contactSpan = elemetsWithClassClose[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

That is why there could be more than one elements containing same class but ids are unique. So in DOM you have to define exactly what element you want to access.
Like if there are two elements using same class like

```
<div class="sample">Bla Bla Bla</div>
<div class="sample">No Bla Bla</div>
```

Then `document.getElementsByClassName("sample")[0];` is the first element (at 0 index of array like object) having that class and
`document.getElementsByClassName("sample")[1];` is the second element having that class.